# X-Editable & PHP MySQL tables

Tags: php, jquery, datatable, x-editable

I'm looking at using X-Editable in my tables, when I pull the table data through from the database, that works all fine, my issue is when I add the X-Editable to it, the first row is only the row that is editable.

All the other rows are showing under a hyperlink but dont have the dashed line underneath, and when click on them they just put the # in the address bar after the *.php

What have I missed to be able have all rows editable?

```
<table id="userinfo" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>MeetingStart</th>
    <th>Details</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
    $info = db::getInstance()->query('SELECT * FROM information');
    foreach ($info->results() as $info) {
?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="groupname" data-type="select" data-pk="1" data-value="5" data-source="/groups" data-original-title="Select group">
            <?php echo $info->name; ?>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" id="meeting_start" data-type="datetime" data-pk="1" data-url="/post" data-placement="right" title="Set date & time">                                                            
            <?php echo $info->meetingstart; ?>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td><?php echo $info->details; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }; ?>
</tbody>
```

Screenshot of the problem
[image: X-Editable issue]

Comment: Is the PK 1 for every record? Or does each record have it's own id?

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate DOM ID's:

```
foreach(...) {
    <a href="#" id="groupname" 
                    ^^^^^^^^^
```

Since DOM IDs **MUST** be unique, the system is properly stopping when it finds the first matching DOM node. You're outputting the SAME id for every row in your table.

Comment: Yup, maybe append the primary key for each record onto the end of the id's in each row to make them unique.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry I'm following what I've seen on the X-Editable site, so what your saying is that each row would need it's own data-pk="?", using your foreach(...) example how do I determine this, sorry not 100% understanding it yet :)

Comment: no idea about x-editable, but if each row needs a unique id of some sort, then yeah. `data-pk="$id_from_database"` would probably be the easiest

Comment: Thanks yes, tried that and it gave each row an id, but still can only edit the 1st row. I've posted a screenshot of what is happening to help understand the problem

Comment: Why would the editable section only work on the first row and not all rows within the dataset? The hyperlink shows for each row, but not the click able aspect which then uses the X-Editable source